# Elements on webpage autosizing

Tags: web, responsive-design, html, autosize, autoscaling

Right now I am having this requirement to make the website so that whenever the users of the site re-size their browsers, the elements on the page will adjust accordingly so they can still view the page in a organized but full view.

For example, when the page is in the maximum window, there should be six columns in the body area, when user re-size the browser to smaller, it will automatically change to 4 columns(which thus will add more rows than previous) or less.

I **don't** think this is the "responsive web design", which in my opinion should just be like: the page looks different in different device or browsers.

Anyone could shred some light on how could I make it or recommend some tutorials or blogs?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Appearantly I was wrong about this:

> I don't think this is the "responsive web design", which in my opinion
>   should just be like: the page looks different in different device or
>   browsers.

Turns out it should be responsive web design.

I am sure people who asked same questions should be able to find a lot of this stuff online, just search "responsive webdesign sample" etc

Here is one example, in Chinese though.
http://www.tuicool.com/articles/vEfQJz